# dbus and qdbus not working suddenly

Tags: raspbian, python, bluetooth, pi-4, dbus

I am using dbus and qdbus to control my phone from a pi using Bluetooth to pause play etc. songs and all of a sudden dbus and qdbus dont work anymore

All other functions work i can head music from he pi from my phone but cant control the phone anymore and tried reinstalling rasbian and sending the commands manually and didn't work
here is a sample of the commands i am sending

```
qdbus --system org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_64_A2_F9_E2_E4_B2/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Track

dbus-send --system --type=method_call --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_64_A2_F9_E2_E4_B2/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Some useful commands to get more debug information from the system are:

Have the `bluetoothctl` tool running in a different terminal when you are running your commands and it may give you more information

More detailed bluetooth log information can be found with `sudo btmon -t |& tee ~/btmon.log`

DBus debug information is available with `dbus-monitor --system`